# bash string replacement with similar cases

Tags: string, bash, replace

I am reading lines of a document that can contain these regexps (no single quotes included, double quotes included:

```
' "text" '
```

or

```
' "text1/text2" '
```

I would like to use a bash script to replace text to obtain these two different outputs:

```
' PRE text POST '
```

or

```
' ANOTHERPRE text1 MID text2 POST '
```

I was trying to use string replace {string // / }, but i don't seem to be able to keep the 'text' parts in between the string i want to replace.

The actual problem is that the string outer delimiters are the same in both cases, the difference between the cases is the "/", which should indicate that i can use ANOTHERPRE and MID.

any suggestion on how to do this in bash?

As an example, I have the following line:

```
 hello "user" you are "alive/10"
```

and i want to produce:

```
hello PRE user POST you are ANOTHERPRE alive MID 10 POST
```

Comment: done, thanks i forgot

Answer (score 1):

I think this is straightforward:

```
 sed 's/"/ PRE /;s/"/ POST /;s#/# MID #' <<< YourString
```

example:

```
kent$ sed 's/"/ PRE /;s/"/ POST /;s#/# MID #' <<< ' "text1/text2" '
  PRE text1 MID text2 POST  

kent$ sed 's/"/ PRE /;s/"/ POST /;s#/# MID #' <<< ' "text" '       
  PRE text POST
```

Comment: i need to produce a different PRE in the first case (it was called ANOTHERPRE)

Comment: also, will it work on a line with two different occurences, one of "text" and one of "text1/text2"?